# Inner Join and Interval?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, intervals

I have two tables
meteor_Events and video_Events and the common fields are Date and Time

I want to search meteor_events where the date and time match any video events so using this query it works fine

```
SELECT
meteor_events.event_id,
meteor_events.fname,
meteor_events.date,
meteor_events.Time
FROM
Video_Events
INNER JOIN
meteor_events
ON
    Video_Events.Date = meteor_events.date AND
    Video_Events.Time = meteor_events.Time
```

I now want to refine this and bring back results where the date matches but the time matches if the meteor_events.Time is plus or minus 2 seconds

ie if the Video_Events.Time is say 00:12:34 bring back results if the meteor_events.Time is between 00:12:32 and 00:12:36

I think I need to use Interval but am not sure ?

Pointers appreciated

Kind Regards
John Berman

Answer (score 0):

So logical thought got me there i added this

Video_Events.Time - meteor_events.Time between -2 AND 2

Regards John B